# Add a clickable link which opens in the outlook mail

Tags: shell-script

I want to add a clickable link in my email script which opens in the outlook.
The clickable link will be a Distribution list.

I am aware of a "a href" tag but not sure what to pass to it.
Below is a part of script:

```
echo " <p> Please reach out to the Team (ABC@XYZ.com) team in case of any questions. </p>
```

Comment: You're looking for a [mailto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) link.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is regarding HTML and is not specific to U/L.

Comment: Haxiel-- Yes, instead to pointing to the browser her , it should open an outlook mail window. That's my question.

Comment: Have you read through the Wikipedia link I've provided? `Clicking on the hyperlink automatically opens the default email client, with the destination email address pre-filled.`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Thanks a lot. It's working as expected!!